# How can I achive Continuous Integration and Deployment for many projects in one solution?

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, appveyor

**What we use:**

We use mercurial and bitbucket for repositories. Appveyor and kudu for continous integration and deployment. We are using visual studio 2015 as IDE.

**What we have:**

We have different web projects. They share some other projects. All of web projects have their own solution. Every solution have their own repository.

If there is change on develop branch. Appveyor builds this repository, tests and deploys it.

If there is change on default, kudu builds this repository and deploys it.

**What we want:**

We want to merge all of these projects in one solution. But I couldn't figure it out, how I can achive continous integration or deployment.

If I change something on webproject1, I just want to build and deploy webproject1. The other webprojects in solution neither should be built nor deployed.

Comment: It seems that you don't really need 1 solution. You want to  have all projects open on the same instance of visual studio? Is that the reason why you want a single solution?

Comment: It's related with development (debuging,dependicies,nuget etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a single repository will help you. Using relative path to include the shared libraries from your different applications.

Each application can still have its own Solution file and your CI setup also stays as it is. What changes is that the shared projects you have across all applications will be referenced with relative path. E.g.:

`Repository root\Core\Component1\Component1.csproj
 Repository root\Core\Component2\Component2.csproj
 Repository root\Applications\App1\App1.sln
 Repository root\Applications\App1\Domain\Domain.csproj
 Repository root\Applications\App1\Web\Web.csproj
 Repository root\Applications\App2\App2.sln
 Repository root\Applications\App2\Domain\Domain.csproj
 Repository root\Applications\App2\Web\Web.csproj`

Now your different application can include the Core\Components they need by adding existing project to solution using relative path.

Your continuous integration system will have VCS triggers watching the app and dependencies so only relevant changes fire a build. 
So if App1 developer makes a change on Component1, and Component1 is also used by App2, the build server will trigger a build to App1 and App2, signaling any breaking changes. However if App2 doesn't not depend on Component1, then only App1 will build.
This is achieved by configuring the build triggers for your applications.

One benefit of this strategy vs having a single .sln is that you won't have to build everything each time you build solution (nor configure what projects to build each time you work on a different app)

Also note that you can achieve this with multiple repositories. But that means you'd need to check them out at the correct location so your relative paths work. It's also quite obscure since if you checkout App1 and try to build it. It simply won't work and you'll have to figure out which other repos to check out, etc.

You are using Mercurial but FYI, the way (one of) this would be handled with Git is with [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: You can ask if you have questions. Would this approach help you?